# Como faço para conectar em outro banco de dados usando a conexão que já tenho

Tags: php

Como faço para conectar em outro banco de dados usando a conexão que já tenho e funciona perfeitamente em outro banco?

Quando mudo apenas o nome da conexão aparece:

> Notice: Undefined variable: conn2 in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\loja\funcao\conecta2.php on line 22

Eis o código:

```
<?php
function conecta2( ){
  if(!defined("HOST")){
     define('HOST','localhost');
  }
  if(!defined("BD")){
     define('BD','cadastro');
  }
  if(!defined("USER")){
     define('USER','root');
  }
  if(!defined("PASS")){
     define('PASS','');
  }
try {
$conn2 = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.BD.'', ''.USER.'', ''.PASS.'');
$conn2->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
}
catch(PDOException $erro){
echo $erro->getMessage();
}
return $conn2; // esta é a linha 22
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O seu return deve ser incluído dentro do `try`:

```
//...
try {
    $conn2 = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.BD.'', ''.USER.'', ''.PASS.'');
    $conn2->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    return $conn2;
}
catch(PDOException $erro){
    //echo $erro->getMessage();
    return false;
}
```

O erro ocorre porque a sua variável `conn2` é criada dentro do `try`. Se a conexão com a base de dados falha, o que provavelmente aconteceu, ela não é instanciada e o interpretador pula para o bloco `catch` informando qual o erro ocorrido.

Repare que comentei a linha:

```
echo $erro->getMessage();
```

Utilize essa linha apenas para debug; também adicionei dentro do bloco `catch` o `return false;` caso a conexão com a base de dados não seja possível.

Assim será possível fazer, por exemplo, a verificação da conexão:

```
$conn = conecta2();
if($conn) {
    //operações CRUD
} else {
    echo "Não foi possível conectar a base de dados.";
}
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado

Comment: @ClaytonCampos sabes marcar a resposta como certa?